# What point release(s) does my aspnet mvc app run against if it targets ".NET Core 3.1"?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I recently updated our .net core asp.net mvc app, in the project properties, the Target Framework is ".NET Core 3.1".  In the .csproj file I see:

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
```

At the time I built it the specific version was 3.1.3 which was listed as LTS (long term support).
If I expand the Dependencies -> then Frameworks -> right click on Microsoft.AspNetCore.App -> properties I see:

```
Version    3.1.3
```

QA tested the app and were preparing to release it.

But in the weeks that have followed, I noticed Microsoft released 3.1.4 (now listed as LTS).  I'm confused on the issue of which version of .NET Core my app can run against in deployment.

Can the app run in a customer/deployment environment that has 3.1.4 installed since **I never specified 3.1.3 explicitly**.  Or can it only run against 3.1.3 because that was the latest on my machine when I built it?

Thanks for the help, I feel stupid for not knowing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misunderstood the LTS concept, https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core

The only key point is that "Customers choosing LTS will need the latest patch update installed to qualify for support". You can use whatever patch version (3.1.x) till you need to upgrade to the latest when receiving support services from Microsoft. You should try to upgrade often to the latest patch version though, as it ships security updates.

Different deployment approaches (framework dependent or self-contained) also have impact on how you upgrade for yourself or your customers, but that's rather lengthy to discuss. You'd better set up a few experiments in a lab environment to explore further.

Comment: That link indicates that the app will start using the latest patch version...
"If a system is running 1.0 and 1.0.1 has been released, 1.0.1 will need to be installed as a first step. Once a patch update has been installed applications will begin using the update by default."

I will indeed do some testing to confirm but that seems pretty clear

Comment: This link confirms original given by @lexli giving more detail...see the "Advantages - Uses the latest patched runtime"  [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#publish-runtime-dependent)